# Spring Boot GET Request gives 200 OK status, but Postman returns {} as response body and i have proper data in MySQl database

Tags: spring-boot

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {

   
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {

    @Id
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int clientId;
    @Column
    String clientName;
    @Column
    String clientEmail;
    @Column
    String clientPhone;

    public Client(){
        super();

    }

    public Client(int client_id,String client_name,String client_email,String client_phone){
        super();
        this.clientId = client_id;
        this.clientName = client_name;
        this.clientEmail = client_email;
        this.clientPhone = client_phone;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client{" + "client_id=" + clientId + ", client_name='" + clientName + '\'' + ", client_email='" + clientEmail + '\'' + ", client_phone='" + clientPhone + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
@RestController
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    ClientService cserv;

    @GetMapping("/getclient")
    public ResponseEntity<Client> getClient(@RequestParam("client_id") int client_id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ofNullable(cserv.getClient(client_id));
    }

    @GetMapping("/getclientbyname/{client_name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Client> getClientByName(@PathVariable("client_name") String client_name) {
        return ResponseEntity.ofNullable(cserv.getClientByName(client_name));
    }
}
```

`Service`

```
@Service
public class ClientService {
    @Autowired
    ClientRepository crepo;

    public Client getClient(int client_id) {
        Client c;
        Optional<Client> optionalClient = crepo.findById(client_id);
        try{
            c = optionalClient.get();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            c=null;
        }
        return c;
    }
    public Client getClientByName(String client_name) {
       Client c;
       Optional<Client> cl = crepo.getClientByName(client_name);
       try{
        c = cl.get();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
        c=null;
       }
       return c;
    }
}
```

`Repository`

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client,Integer> {

   public Optional<Client> findById(int client_id);

   @Query("select c from Client c where clientName=:client_name")
  public Optional<Client> getClientByName(String client_name); 
  
}
```

Postman Response

```
GET http://localhost:8080/getclientbyname/Client%201
200
122 ms
Network
addresses: {…}
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.35.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 6186ba22-b040-4bcb-9da9-4932c662d41f
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Response Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 04 Dec 2023 18:31:17 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
Response Body
{}
```

I tried for both methods .getting same response

> http://localhost:8080/getclient?client_id=1
>
> http://localhost:8080/getclientbyname/mahendra

Comment: `optionalClient.isPresent()` this hurts my eyes. Just return the `Optional` from the method and in your controller return a `ResponseEntity` with `ResponseEntity.of(your-nullable)`. Using `Optional.isPresent` is an anti pattern and abuse of Optional.

Comment: Still getting same response

Comment: Show your updated code and the `Client` as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum  added client entity and updated code

Comment: Have you made sure that your repo/service is actually returning something? What configuration you are using on the project for it to actually understand snake case? Are you using a custom naming strategy? If you didn't your entities should not use snake_case, the attributes should use camelCase

Comment: @JorgeCampos  applied camelCasing still same response ....i have added postman response and updated code

Comment: There are no getters, no getters no properties in JSON.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank You . Issue Resolved